# re.search() only matches the first occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the pattern:

```
<--Header Title-->
some body text
```

The following only matches the first occurrence:

```
string1 = """<-- Option 1 -->
Nice text
<--Final stuff-->
Listing all
of
the
text
"""

regex = re.compile(r"<--([\w\s]+)-->([\s\S]*?)(?=\n<--|$)") 
m = regex.search(string1)
print m.groups()
```

Which results in:

```
(' Option 1 ', '\nNice text')
```

However, [it seems to work fine using pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=%3C--(%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B)--%3E(%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cn%3C--%7C%24)&test_string=%3C--%20Option%201%20--%3E%0ANice%20text%0A%0A%3C--Final%20stuff--%3E%0AListing%20all%0Aof%0Athe%0Atext&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) for `search`, and did you look for an alternative function to use instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) only matches the first occurrence within the string. You want [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) or [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

> **re.search**
>
> Scan through string looking for the **first location** where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Finditer returns match objects for all locations within the target string, yielding an iterator, while findall returns the substrings for all matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('a', 'ababababa')
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

>>> x = list(re.finditer('a', 'ababababa'))
>>> x
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='a'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 5), match='a'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 7), match='a'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 9), match='a'>]
>>> x[0].group()
'a'
```