# Python regex not working with special characters

Tags: python

**SOLVED: it replaced the " symbols in the file with ' (in the data strings)**

Do you know a way to only search for 1 or more words (not numbers) between **["** and **\n**?

This works on regexr.com, but not in python

https://regexr.com/3tju7

¨

`(?<=\[\")(\D+)(?=\\n)`

"S": ["Something\n13/8-2018 09:00 to 11:30

¨

Python code:

re.search('(?<=[\")(\D+)(?=\n)', str(**data**))

I think `\[`, `\"` and `\\n` is the problem, I have tried to use raw in python

`re.search('(?<=\[\")(\D+)(?=\\n)', '"S": ["Something\n13/8-201809:00 to 11:30').group()`

This worked but I have to use "**data**" because I have multiple strings, and it won't let me use **.group()** on that.

Error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Comment: What's in `data`? I suspect the problem is not in the regex

Comment: Yes, but is it a dictionary, a list, a string? And if so, what are the types in the dict/list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095205/re-search-only-matches-the-first-occurance

Comment: We need to see more code. What is *actually* in data? Not the file, the python object that is assigned to it

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `\n` is being interpreted as a newline, instead of the literal characters `\` and `n`. You can use a simpler regex, `\["([\w\s]+)$`, along with the `MULTILINE` flag, without modifying the data.

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '"S": ["Something\n13/8-201809:00 to 11:30'
>>> pattern = '\["([\w\s]+)$'
>>> m = re.search(pattern, data, re.MULTILINE)
>>> m.group(1)
'Something'
```

Comment: You can simplify the expression to `(?<=\[\")([A-Za-z]+)`, no lookahead needed if you don't use `\D+`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP said this `re.search('(?<=\[\")(\D+)(?=\\n)', '"S": ["Something\n13/8-201809:00 to 11:30').group()` works, so of course changing it to raw won't fix his problem

Comment: @UnbearableLightness What about `\s` characters? The OP asks for _a way to only search for 1 or more words (not numbers)_. I understand this as meaning that the capture may contain whitespaces.

Comment: @ZachGates didn't mean to, my bad! Hopefully this gets OP on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a r before the string with the pattern, that marks the string as "raw". This stops python from evaluating escaped characters before passing them to the function

```
re.search(r'\search', string)
```

Or:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'pattern')
rgx.search(string)
```

Comment: Tried copying that, had the same issue until I made the inputstring a rawstring. I guess that you get your input from reading a file rather than as a string; could it be that the \n in the source has beed treated as newline instead of backslash-n ?

Comment: If it is a string in the python file, write the letter r in front of the quotation marks. (Like it is in the code line above). If it is a file, it should be correct when you load it.